# Can a std::array<T, N> release its data?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

Consider as an example the `unique_ptr` and its `release` method that *returns a pointer to the managed object and releases the ownership*.
Is there any way to *release* the ownership of the underlying array of a `std::array`?

---

<sub>Ok, one could use a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a `std::array` and that's all. Anyway, the latter has a few nice features like the `size` member method that are useful sometimes.</sub>

Comment: Sounds like a `std::unique_ptr<std::array<...>>` would work. `std::array` doesn't choose where the data lives.

Comment: @chris Yeah, do not consider it a real world problem. I know what would work there. I was just curious to know if there exists a way to release those data. I found myself saying _well, it would have been useful_ and that's all. :-)

Comment: This seems like a more general question; Can you 'rescue' a member from an object before it goes out of scope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any way to release the ownership of the underlying array of a std::array?

No.  A `std::array` is just a wrapper for a raw array.  It can be reassigned but that is actually a copy operation of all the elements in the array. The destination array does not point to the source array.

You should also note that a `std::array` and a `std::unique_ptr<type[]>` are different in that the `std::array` size must be know at compile time where the `std::unique_ptr<type[]>` size can be set at run time.  All `std::unique_ptr<type[]>` really does is wrap a `type * name = new type[some_size]`.

Comment: Note that if one wants to keep the "nice features" of `std::array`, it is trivial to write a wrapper class that is composed of a `std::unique_ptr<type[]> buffer` and a `size_t size`, with member `begin`, `end`, `empty`, `size`, and of course `release`. Basically a light `std::vector` without the dynamic resizing.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Would that still be an aggregate type?

Comment: I guess not, I wouldn't want to expose the `size` of the wrapper, it should be correct on construction.

Comment: Though the said wrapper can have a `std::initializer_list<type>` constructor that makes it look like an aggregate type, just like `std::array`. The wrapper would allocate the owned buffer internally, and `release` it on demand.

Comment: @KABoissonneault That would work.  Gives you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, an `std::array` is just a simple wrapper around a native array, so it is on the stack and cannot release its contents unless it goes out of scope when the contents are automatically popped from the stack

You should consider using a `std::vector` instead. Since you are already dealing with an array on the heap.  You can then `std::move` the vector into another one to "transfer" ownership of the contents.  For example

```
another_vec = std::move(old_vec); // now another_vec has the contents
```

**Note** If you use a `unique_ptr` the array you are getting is on the heap and not on the stack!  So you might be better off using a `std::vector` and its `data()` function instead.  But I am not completely sure of your use case.

**Another note** Another thing that is not that obvious when thinking about using an `std::array` is that the type is a heavyweight object, this means that the regular rvalue optimizations *might* not work as optimally since it is not as trivial to move as a `vector`

Comment: Although, `std::vector` cannot "release" its internal data either.

Comment: @user2079303 Yep you can (at least in a non guaranteed way, meaning that the implementation optimizes the actual release, which is probably better than what you want anyway).  Take a look at `std::vector::shrink_to_fit`

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "*`release` method that returns a pointer to the managed object and releases the ownership*" means. `shrink_to_fit` does nothing of the sort. *If* it reallocates to a shrinked array, the original memory is destroyed, rather than "released" and returned to the caller.

Comment: @user2079303 Wasn't there a C++17 proposal for that? I hope it got accepted

Comment: @user2079303 yeah! I didn't know you were referring to ownership when you just said "release".

Comment: @KABoissonneault there is a proposal. According to [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/sd-1.htm), it has not been adopted although The document is from the last year though. Curious: yeah, I could have been more explicit that I refer to "release" as defined in the question. It's quite ambiguous out of context.

Comment: @user2079303 Looks like we're still stuck with using `std::unique_ptr<Node[]>` when dealing with C libraries frameworks :/

Comment: @KABoissonneault C libraries don't typically take ownership of pointers they use though, do they? I think that would be a major design flaw.

Comment: @downvoter could you maybe suggest what I can do to make my answer better?

Comment: @Curious You should probably suggest an answer that has a `release` that returns a pointer to the internal buffer

Comment: @KABoissonneault OP was not asking for an interface with a `release` method but rather a way to release the contents of an array.  That is why I suggested the way to do that with a vector instead.

Answer (score 1):

«releasing» a std::array basically means calling the destructor and using the memory for something else.

You can explicitly destroy an explicitly constructed std::array by using the std::*::destroy functionality found in the standard library or calling the destructor explicitly.

This is something you usually want to avoid, unless you are implementing very basic data structures where you have no other choice. One use case is if you want to control when and how you construct and destruct a global array without an indirection through a pointer.

C++17 may provide the new functions
[destroy_at, destroy and destroy_n](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0040r2.html#II_Summary_11) to explicitly destruct objects.

See also the [C++ FAQ on destructors](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors).